# Why use standard types as template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, int, polymorphism

I'm currently learning C++ and I've reached the chapter about templates in the book I'm reading.

And they've just shown an example of using an integer as a template parameter, it look's like this:

```
template<class T, int N> class array{...}
```

in the example N is used to determine the size of the array, but my question is why would you even do so, if you can also just pass the size as a parameter of the constructor for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter to the constructor can be passed at runtime, i.e. you don't need to know its value at compile-time. However, the value of a  template parameter must be known at compile time.

If you are going to allocate an array statically, its size must be known at compile-time. Therefore, a template parameter to determine the size is suitable.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. Thanks a lot. :)